# How to filter json data using UISegmentedControl in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdateformatter, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working as iOS apps developer. The JSON response I need to consume is available at http://pastie.org/9304213 . Using this I want to filter the data so that in my UISegmentcontrol for 3 buttons. i.e 1. Day   2. Week    3.Month.

->If i click Date segment control it displays today data in UITableview controller.

->If i click Week segment control it displays current week data in UITableview controller.

->If i click Month segment control it displays current month data in UITableview controller.

I am new to iOS programming. Please guide.

Comment: Please write out some code that you want to get editted or suggestions about.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. For fetching and parsing JSON data, You can use this in your Controller .m file. But do have a check on whether your server is sending you JSON in proper format or not. JSON should start with '[' or '{'.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourServiceURL"];
NSData *response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Now you have your data in a NSDictionary object and you can extract particular data using the `objectForKey` or `valueForKey` functions like this :

```
_array = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"keyField"];
```

Now if you want to toggle between 3 switch values, you can try something like this.

```
-(IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    if ([_segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex]==0)
    {
        //your Code
    }
    else if ([_segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex]==1)
    {
        //your Code
    }
    else 
    {
        //your Code
    }
}
```

You have to connect this event with the `valueChanged` event of the `UISegmentControl`.This will do its job when you click on anyone of the segment values. It will identify the index of the clicked segment and will run into appropriate loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response.i Have lot of doubts.please come to Chat room "Talk-4-ios".plz bro